# How can I shorten my codes about the Stringrequest?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have some methods that receive data from google app script but Its a little bit long to put the same code for all the methods.

For example this is my checkIn method but I need to create checkOut method or UpdateReservation that receive the actual function from javascript in the google. There is a way to shorten this Volley Stringrequestcode.

Or atleast can I use that kind of coding or function with firebase and much easier ?

```
private void checkIn() {
                final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Reservations.this);
                final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url",
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {


                            }

                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            }
                        }
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> parmas = new HashMap<>();

                        //here we pass params
                        parmas.put("action","checkIn");

                        return parmas;
                    }
                };
                int socketTimeOut = 50000;// u can change this .. here it is 50 seconds
                RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
                stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


            }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need a more compact way to write that piece of code. Am I correct?

You can use lambdas to write listeners in a more compact way:

```
 StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url",
            (response) -> {
                //Handle response
            },
            (error) -> {
                //Handle error
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> parmas = new HashMap<>();

            //here we pass params
            parmas.put("action","checkIn");

            return parmas;
        }
    };
```

If the `getParams(...)` method for each case just add an `action` key to the params map you can create a class that extends `StringRequest` with this functionality.

```
public class CustomStringRequest extends StringRequest {
    private String action;

    public CustomStringRequest(int method, String url, String action, Response.Listener listener, Response.ErrorListener el) {
        super(method, url, listener, el);
        this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> parmas = new HashMap<>();

        //here we pass params
        parmas.put("action", action);

        return parmas;
    }
}
```

And then in each method you can write your request as follows:

```
request = new CustomStringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url", "checkIn",
     (response) -> {
         //Handle response
     },
     (error) -> {
         //Handle error
     });
```

Note that the "checkIn" type action has been passed into the `CustomStringRequest` constructor!

So finally you get something like this

```
private void checkIn() {
    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Reservations.this);
    final StringRequest stringRequest = new CustomStringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url", "checkIn",
            (response) -> {
                //Handle response
            },
            (error) -> {
                //Handle error
            });
    int socketTimeOut = 50000;// u can change this .. here it is 50 seconds
    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.....super(method, url, listener, el); here method componenet has an error says' 

Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'com.android.volley.Request.Method', required: 'int' more...'

Comment: what is that part for in my cde ...............................................................................
int socketTimeOut = 50000;// u can change this .. here it is 50 seconds
                RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
                stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

Comment: I edited my answer to fix the super(method, url, listener, el); problem. About the last part in your code it simply sets a retry policy. Basically it retries to perform the request if it fails to execute for timeout in the first 50 seconds.

Comment: Also requestQueue.add(stringRequest); is very important! It adds the request to the queue of request to be executed.

Comment: thanks i approved your answer , ok last question. I have appscript and that url has already an action like https://myapscript/exec?action=checkIn  in that case if I use only that url can not shorten it more :?

Comment: I'm sorry but I haven't fully understand your last question. This is the url of the request you set as argument for StringRequest, am I right? What do you want to shorten more? Maybe you don't want to add the "checkIn" argument to the CustomStringRequest because it is already inside the url?

Comment: you can parse it from the string but in this case I don't think the readability improvement will benefit the overall code quality.

Comment: I almost get it.... I create an activity and extends it to StringRequest like this

public class Model extends StringRequest(){
private int id = -1;
    private String title = "";
    private String url = "b_IAgNCzcKUZaK/exec";
    private StringRequest strq ;

    public YourModel(int method, String url, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {


        super(method, url, listener, errorListener);



    }

}

Comment: now I need to reach that activity to use that java script on the URL